# Servicios en Azure Scheduleados

Tags: azure, servicio

Tengo un servicio windows, que corre cada cierto tiempo y descarga informacion desde una API. Ahora bien queria llevar este servicio a un servidor cloud, en este caso Azure.
Mi idea, NO es crear una virtual machine sino que queria saber si alguno conoce alguno de los servicios de azure que permita schedulear eventos cada cierto tiempo, y dispararlo automaticamente.

Muchas gracias,

Comment: Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta está pidiendo recomendaciones de algún recurso externo, lo cual causará su cierre. Por otro lado, ¿porqué usar una palabra inventada *schedulear* cuando en nuestro rico caatellano tenemos palabras para definir la tarea (*programar, agendar, etc*)? Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Gracias Mauricio contreras por la aclaracion, de como preguntar.
Volviendo a la pregunta, encontre lo que buscaba. Les dejo el link donde encontre la respuesta: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create

Muchas gracias,